# Is it possible to give 2 targets for ssh monitoring in single prometheus job?

Tags: monitoring, prometheus

My scenario is that in blackbox.yml, i have ssh_banner module which checks for ssh like below.

```
ssh_banner:
 prober: tcp
    tcp:
      query_response:
      - expect: "^SSH-2.0-"
```

Below is relevant the prometheus.yml:

```
 - job_name: 'ssh_test'
    scrape_interval: 20s
    metrics_path: /probe
    params:
      module: ["ssh_banner"]
      target: [ "node1:22", "node2:22"]
    static_configs:
     - targets:
        - 'blackbox:9115'
```

I can see it is only doing ssh test for node1 not for node2. Is there any way to put in sigle place. I know creating a separate job would solve this problem. but number of servers can be many. so creating a separate job for every node doesn't looks good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [follow the documentation](https://github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter#prometheus-configuration) and add relabelling rules to all this to work. There is a [guide](https://www.robustperception.io/checking-if-ssh-is-responding-with-prometheus/) for this exact use case too.

Comment: Thanks brian... it is working. i read this page before. but ignore relabeling part :) :)